# Flutter Grid with a lot of input fields - Is there a smart way?

Tags: flutter, dart, grid

I am losing my mind on this one.

I build a Grid with multiple input fields and it works but the code is duplicated in a horrible way and i can't seem to find a solution for this.

[image: This is my Grid]

As you can see on the image i already have 45 input-fields plus the fields with the names.
Since i need the input of all those textfields i hardcoded every item in this grid.

```
  var erdbeerenABController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeeren13UhrController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeeren15UhrController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeeren17UhrController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeerenEBController = TextEditingController();

  var erdbeerenGesternABController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeerenGestern13UhrController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeerenGestern15UhrController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeerenGestern17UhrController = TextEditingController();
  var erdbeerenGesternEBController = TextEditingController();

  ...


          Container(
        height: 400,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
        child: GridView.count(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisCount: 6,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('AB'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('13 Uhr'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('15 Uhr'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('17 Uhr'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('EB'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Erd'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(controller: erdbeerenABController),
              color: Colors.blue[200],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(controller: erdbeeren13UhrController),
              color: Colors.blue[300],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(controller: erdbeeren15UhrController),
              color: Colors.blue[400],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(controller: erdbeeren17UhrController),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(controller: erdbeerenEBController),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Erd G'),
              color: Colors.blue[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: TextField(controller: erdbeerenGesternABController),
              color: Colors.blue[200],
            ),


  ...
```

Is there anyway to build this grid in a clean code way? I just don't see how to keep track of all the inputfields if i do it in a different approach but this feels so horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the official Flutter doc:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Or there are several options:

```
GridView.count(...)

GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
)
```

```
GridView.builder(...)

GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemBuilder: (_, index) => FlutterLogo(),
  itemCount: 4,
)
```

```
GridView(...)

GridView(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
)
```

```
GridView.custom(...)

GridView.custom(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  childrenDelegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
    [
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
      FlutterLogo(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

```
GridView.extent(...)

GridView.extent(
  maxCrossAxisExtent: 400,
  children: <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
    FlutterLogo(),
  ],
)
```

Just an example. I didn't do it according to your situation but it should work for you as well.

Comment: I am aware that these exist but i dont understand how to implement them while still keeping track of the input in the inputfields. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

use this pin_code_text_field package [pin_code_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_text_field)

give maxLength =5 to create 5 fields in row.
this can really help and can reduce TextEditingController() to 9, use  decoration to fill color to each field instead of the containers.